How to use rsbuild to load module federation library?
I am trying to use rsbuild to replace my webpact react project, one task is to use module federation to load remote library, below is the code:
export const mfConfig= {
name: 'MF_WEBCHAT',
library: { type: 'var', name: 'MF_WEBCHAT' },
remotes: {
    MF_UI_COMP: "MF_UI_COMP@http://localhost:9000/remoteEntry.js"
},
exposes: {
    './AiWebchat': './src/App'
},
filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
remoteType: 'module',
shared: {
   
}};

and this is the rsbuild.config.mjs
    const PORT = 3003;
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [pluginReact(),
  ],
  server: {
    port: PORT,
    strictPort: true,
  },
  tools: {
    rspack: {
      plugins: [ new ModuleFederationPlugin(mfConfig)]
    }
  }
});

But when I start the application, I do not see the external micro-fronted being loaded at all from http://localhost:9000/remoteEntry.js
Can anyone tell me if rsbuild.dev can be used to load external MS Frontend or just used to generate ms frontend?
Thanks
